# R.Neighbors with large neighborhoods?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm running into problems running the r.neighbors GRASS command in QGIS. Although it will run for small neighborhoods as soon as I increase my neighborhood above a certain number it becomes unbearably slow. I don't understand why Focal Statistics on Arcmap will do this in the blink of an eye while R.Neighbors takes ages?

Comment: Which statistic are you computing?

Comment: How many pixels are involved?